# passing the data to the selected cell of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I am working in winforms. In that, I have a `datagridview`. I have transferred the selected cell value to a new form, `form2`

But now I want to re-transfer the textbox value which is in `form2` to the `datagridview` cell.

How can i do that?

On the `form2`, along with `label1` there is `button1` and a `textbox`. I want that when the `textbox` is filled and `button1` is pressed, it will transfer the text from the `textbox` to the cell which was selected.

I have used following code for this. 
The code of `button_click` event...

But an error occurs as follwing.

> " object reference not set to instance of an object "

Comment: Did you try debugging your solution? You are using CurrentCell before you show the form, so this Property might be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do recreate the main form inside of form 2, which is probably not what you need.
Change the code to this:

```
private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 form2 f2 = new form2();
 f2.label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
 f2.ShowDialog();
 dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value = f2.textBox1.Text;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir you have solved my big problem.
and can you explain what is this dialogresult = dialogresult.ok?

Comment: sir the problem is when the form2 opens and i closes the form then the cell value is set to blank how can i avoid that? can i add validation

Comment: @shariq_khan DialogResult is a return value of a dialog box, you can read more on msdn. Yes, you can validate it. You should handle FormClosing event of form2 and check there if textBox1.Text is empty or not. Search for examples on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Design Properties of `DataGridView`
`dataGridView1.Modifiers = Public`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var f = new Form2 { Owner = this})
        {
            f.valueFromSelectedCell = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string valueFromSelectedCell { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = valueFromSelectedCell;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f = this.Owner as Form1;
        var currentCell = f.dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
        f.dataGridView1[currentCell.ColumnIndex, currentCell.RowIndex].Value = textBox1.Text;
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: sir i didint got what you have done.. in which form is the datagridview?

Comment: in your main Form. look from properties of `dataGridView1` from your `form1` modify the `Modifiers` to `Public`

Comment: and what is this two form for? i have a datagridview on a form1 and when contextmenu is clicked it it transfer the value to the next form2 and i have second form2 where there is a button in which it transfer the text from the form2 textbox to the datagridview selected cell  and what you have done here? can you explain please